# Facebook C# SDK MVC3 - client.Get("me/picture") Invalid JSON string error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

On the Graph API explorer if I do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture
```

I am to retrieve my picture. However in Facebook C# SDK MVC 3

if I do

```
var client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
ViewBag.UserPicture = client.Get("me/picture");
```

I get an error

Invalid JSON string

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/me/picture` returns a HTTP redirect to the picture URL so you can use it in an `<img src=...` tag

If you want it back in JSON format, access `/me?fields=picture`

Answer (score 2):

```
var me = client.Get("me", new { fields = "id,name,first_name,last_name,link,username,gender,locale,email,picture,birthday" }) as IDictionary<string, object>;
```